# I am at/in office /café restaurant

Tags: word-choice

Are "at" and "in" interchangeable in these situations and would the meanings of these sentences change if I use "at" instead of "in" and "vise versa? I am asking about BrE.

1. "I am at/in the office now. I am working. I will call you during my coffee break."
2. "I am at/in the office now. My sister forgot her phone at home so I had to bring it to the office." ( I don't work there.)
3. "I am at/in my favourite restaurant right now." (Eating)
4. "I am in/at my favourite cafe now." (Eating)
5. "I am in/at my favourite cafe now. (This is said while I left the table to call my friend.)
6. "I am at/in my favourite restaurant now. (This is said while I left the table to call my friend).

Comment: Yes, "at" and "in" are effectively interchangeable in all of those. If you stepped *outside* the cafe to take the call, then "in" might be not strictly accurate, but still reasonable. The only issue is not with at/in, but with "the office" when you don't work there: people normally use "the" only with their own workplace.

Comment: How is this different to what you asked 5 hours ago? [In/at cafe, restaurant, bank, office,station](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/303382/in-at-cafe-restaurant-bank-office-station)

Comment: @Andy Bonner, do you mean "the" is wrong here because I am not talking about my workplace? "I   am at/in the office now. My sister forgot her phone at home so I had to bring it to the office." ( I don't work there.)

Comment: Yes; "I'm at the office" would be understood as *my* office. This is partly because "the office" is used idiomatically to refer specifically to one's own regular workplace. If I visited my sister's office I might say "I'm at my sister's office," or "at *an* office" would be fine too.

Comment: @FumbleFingers One distinction I see between this question and the earlier one, or the one Astralbee proposed there as a duplicate, is that they address questions of career/occupation rather than literal location. "I'm in banking" is different than "I'm in a bank"; you could also be "at a bank" but not "at banking." Antonia: If the goal is to learn when you *can't* use "at" or "in" interchangeably for locations, you haven't offered a scenario where that's true. But if you changed "left the table" to "stepped outside," then there's a difference.

Comment: If I stand outside the cafe, I might say "I'm at the cafe," but not "in" it. Once I step inside, I could reasonably say either. Changing the location from cafe to restaurant (or bank, or grocery store) has no effect. There's one detail with "office," though: We use "in the office" as its own idiom to mean "on duty" or "not on holiday." But as long as you're asking about actual presence within a building, the same rules apply there.

Comment: @Andy Bonner, you said "at an office" would be fine too. Do "in an office"  and "in my sister's office" work too instead of "at my sister's office"?

Comment: See @PatrickSzalapski's excellent summation. "In the office" is its own unique idiom, and is unrelated to issues of "in/at." (I might say I'm "in the office" even when working from home, as long as I'm not on holiday.) *Aside from that*, you've asked about "in" vs "at" with many different locations, but the effect is always the same, as Patrick elaborates: "at" used with a building includes both inside it and outside but near it, while "in" means "in."

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it's very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These words carry connotations when each is used. "In" implies that you are actually inside the building, whereas "at" is slightly more general--you might be in the building's driveway, or in the parking lot, or inside the building.

> "I am at/in the office now. My sister forgot her phone at home so I had to bring it to the office." ( I don't work there.)

If you don't work there, you probably would not say "*the* office" at all. You'd instead say, "I'm at my sister's office," using "at" to emphasize the more general location--it doesn't matter to the listener whether you are inside or outside.

> "I am at/in my favourite restaurant right now." "I am in/at my favourite cafe now."

Use "in" if you want to emphasize that you are in it as opposed to just outside it, or "at" to emphasize that particular restaurant as opposed to other restaurants or anywhere else you might be.